# Delete user from firebase with firebase-admin sdk and User email

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, firebase-admin

I have the firebase-admin sdk installed and I use a web app.Is there any way to delete user from firebase only using the email of the user.If so how can I do it with python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [user management](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) (auth) APIs of the Admin SDK:

```
user = auth.get_user_by_email(email)
auth.delete_user(user.uid)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_user_by_email` to find the uid of the user you want to delete, and then call `delete_user` to delete it.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#get_user_by_email

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#delete_user